# VBS GetObject will not bind to saved workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I'm trying to write a script which will switch to a specific excel workbook and enter keys, however, the script will only run if the workbook which is being referenced is unsaved.

For example:

If I open a new excel workbook which creates a new workbook named "Book1"; the following works:

Set xl = GetObject("Book1").Application

If I run the above when the workbook has been saved, even if the name remains the same, the above results in the following error: (0x800401E4).

Is anyone aware of this being a problem, or can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? I'd guess the error has something to do with the object name being different from the actual file name, so when excel creates the default workbook the code works because the name of the instance is "Book1" whereas the saved "Book1" is assigned another object name when saved?

Comment: The name actually *isn't* the same after it's been saved - prior to saving it doesn't have an extension.  You need to use the full path after it's saved.

Comment: Hi Comintern, thanks for the response. 

Would this mean changing the above snippet to:
GetObject("Book1.xlsm").Application
or
GetObject("C:\Users\Me\Documents\Book1.xlsm").Application

I've tried both methods, the first results in the previous error. The second with "File name or class name not found during Automation Operation (0x1B0)

Comment: It needs to be the full path - `GetObject("C:\Users\Me\Documents\Book1.xlsm")`.

Comment: Ah, it didn't work the previous time because I accidentally misspelt part of the file path. Everything seems to work perfectly now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure if I needed to close this question as answered, however, it seems that https://stackoverflow.com/users/4088852/comintern has resolved the issue.

> It needs to be the full path -
>   GetObject("C:\Users\Me\Documents\Book1.xlsm").

Thanks,